# DataTrigger C# in resourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, resourcedictionary

I have searched some topics on Stackoverflow, but none seem to work for me.

I set the DataGrid Columns based on columns in a resourceDictionary. (This dictionary consists of DataGridTemplateColumn's.) One of these columns contains binding to a Boolean value. however I do not want 'True' or 'False', I want to have '√' or ''.

This does not seem to work for me ([DataTrigger for Textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846966/datatrigger-for-textblock)). It still keeps the 'True' or 'False'.

This is the textblock inside the template:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding booleanValue}" TextAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding booleanValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="√"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding booleanValue}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

What am I missing or should I change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889834/wpf-trigger-from-a-different-control/24890096#24890096 ..try adding text value inside the style.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem! Can you answer my question? Then I can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **DataTrigger** is not change the value of the Text property because you set it inside the TextBlock declaration. So, once setted, it will never changed. To allow changing, you have to set the value inside the Style.

Comment: Heena is technically right, but I think there's more to explain here... Properties set in a Style (or in a Trigger inside a Style) can be overriden at instance level, and here you're doing just that. But the thing is that you don't even need to set Text to any value at all outside the Trigger. The `Text="{Binding booleanValue}"` piece of code is completely useless and if you simply remove it, the code will work.